# How to code MA change from previous candle?

Tags: pine-script

I am new in pine script. I would like to format the given code for the table cells below:

```
ema1 = ema[0] > ema[1] ? color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 10) : ema[0] == ema[1] ? color.rgb(88, 40, 65, 10) : color.rgb(0, 0, 255, 10)
```

This shows the color of the cell in the table corresponds to the value of ema[0] compared to ema[1]. The problem with this is that the " ema[0] == ema[1] ? " is too precise, such that what I would consider as = to previous value is instead falls to < or > condition, where the difference might as well be decimals. I want to turn the given code such that the = option, if the close of [0] and [1] with value of 0 being equal, to add range like >-0.5 0.5< as under the equal value, instead of the exact 0 value.

[Like the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTJc0.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, maybe using:

```
math.round(ema, 0) == math.round(ema[1], 0)
```

would get the result you are seeking?